# Source angular script files in head from a different file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am in the beginning stages of my project and since I am using angular I have a lot of script files. Controllers, services, directives, 3rd party libraries, etc. This makes the the main html page head very large and not very easy on the eyes.

1. Is there a good way to source these files from another file? I tried referencing another js file and it didn't work.
2. Am I being too picky and should I just let the head grow and leave it be? (I am not sure if I am alone here or not because I have done a ton of google searching and I am not finding anything.)

Comment: You'll probably want to look into bundling and minifying your code and serve it as one request. And you should load them at the end of the body rather than the head.

Comment: I do plan on doing some bundling. This is strictly for code organization for the team. Concerning the placement of the files in the body... I dont know how useful my html would without the js yet considering angular is rending most of my html